# Python3 pyodbc dynamically build update query

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

How can I dynamically build an update query where the number and field names I'm updating are different without having to set up a different update query for every single update statement.

I'm new to python, but in other languages I've seen it be done with a key value pair where you would dynamically do something like:

```
UPDATE my_table SET key1 = value1 WHERE key2 = value2
```

Then you'd pass an array of key value pairs to the function and off you go.

Is the best way to do this in python to just create an update string and pass in the fields? Something like:

```
"UPDATE my_table SET {} = ? WHERE {} = ?".format(key1, key2)
```

Then I guess you'd have to separately pass in the parameters to pyodbc.executemany?

But then I'm not sure how you'd handle a variable number of fields to update. I'm sure there's a way to do this easily, so hopefully someone can clue me in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with vanilla Python and pyodbc the basic process you've described is correct. If you have a list of column names to update

```python
>>> col_names_to_set = ['LastName', 'FirstName']
```

you can build the required items for the SET clause,

```python
>>> set_tokens = ','.join([f'{x}=?' for x in col_names_to_set])
>>> set_tokens
'LastName=?,FirstName=?'
```

include that in your SQL command text,

```python
>>> sql = f"UPDATE TableName SET {set_tokens} WHERE ..."
>>> sql
'UPDATE TableName SET LastName=?,FirstName=? WHERE ...'
```

and then pass that statement to `executemany` along with your list of tuples containing the values to be updated.

Note that for safety you probably should enclose the column names in the delimiters for your SQL dialect, e.g., for SQL Server (T-SQL):

```python
>>> set_tokens = ','.join([f'[{x}]=?' for x in col_names_to_set])
>>> set_tokens
'[LastName]=?,[FirstName]=?'
```